# Access request in SOAP UI at testcase level

Tags: json, groovy, request, soapui, assert

I want to access the request parameter and match it against a particular node in response JSON using groovy scripting.

The following is the code I tried

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(Request.requestContent)
def id = String.valueOf(holder.getNodeValue(“destination”))
```

but SOAP UI comes up with the error "Variable name must start with the letter but found "destination"

I've also tried

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context ) 

def project = context.testCase.testSuite.project

def testSuite = project.getTestSuiteAt(0)
log.info(testSuite.getLabel())
def testCase = testSuite.getTestCaseAt(0)
log.info(testCase.getLabel())
def testStep = testCase.getTestStepAt(0)
log.info(testStep.getLabel())

def teststepname = testCase.getTestStepAt(0).getName().toString() 
def inputHolder = teststepname + "#Request"
log.info(inputHolder);
def holderRawReq = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(inputHolder)
def destination = holderRawReq.getNodeValue("destination")
log.info destination
```

But it shows error "Unexpected end of file after null"

Please help. I appreciate it.

Comment: You're trying to parse JSON using get**Xml**Holder???

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. You can access the request parameter and match it against a particular node in SOAPUI Groovy script.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def request = context.testCase.getTestStepAt(0).getProperty("destination").getValue()
log.info request


//grab the response
def ResponseMessage = messageExchange.response.responseContent
//define a JsonSlurper
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ResponseMessage)

//verify the slurper isn't empty
assert !(jsonSlurper.isEmpty())

assert jsonSlurper.routes[0] != null
log.info jsonSlurper.routes[0].legs[0].end_address
def end_address = jsonSlurper.routes[0].legs[0].end_address

end_address.toString().contains("$request")
```